# Making an Array to Hold Arrays of Character Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, character-arrays

My C is a little more than rusty at the moment, so I'm failing to create something I think should be pretty basic.

Allow me to refer to character arrays as strings for this post.  It will make things clearer for both me and you.

What I have is an array that can hold 1 or more strings.  For instance {"ab", "cd", "ef"}.  I want to make another array to store multiple versions of the array of strings.  So something like {{"ab", "cd", "ef"}, {"gh", "ij"}, {"kl"}}.

What I have right now is:

```
char *arrayOfStrings[50]; // a single array to hold multiple strings
char **arrayOfArraysOfStrings[10]; // array to hold multiple snapshots of arrayOfStrings
```

The array of strings changes over time and I'm using the array of arrays of strings to basically hold historical snapshots of arrayOfStrings.  My problem comes when I need to access the snapshot array for data.  This is the code I have to put stuff into the snapshot array:

```
arrayOfArraysOfStrings[input_index] = arrayOfStrings; // you can assume input_index is updated correctly, I've already checked that.
```

This appears to be incorrect since when I try to access and print out the contents of the snapshot array, it only prints out the information from the most recent arrayOfStrings.  The idea I was going for with this was to store the address of where arrayOfChars is pointing in an entry of the snapshot array so I can access it later.

Right now, access to an entry in the snapshot array is accomplished like this:

```
arrayOfArraysOfChars[historicalIndex][indexOfTargetChar]
```

There are several questions I'm looking to answer:

1. Is the method I outlined appropriate for what I'm trying to do or is there a flaw in my overall logic?
2. What am I doing wrong with my current code and how do I fix it?
3. Is there a better way to do this, and if so, how does initialization of the arrays, addition to the arrays, and reading from the arrays work?

--edit 4/18--
Part of the problem is that I'm setting pointers in arrayOfArraysOfStrings to point to the same thing that arrayOfStrings is pointing to.  That's bad since arrayOfStrings gets edited.  I need some way to duplicate a 2D array...  Preferably by simply allocating a new block of memory for arrayOfStrings to point at.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have one-too-many pointers in both of your arrays.

```
char arrayOfChars[50]; // a single array of characters
char *arrayOfArraysOfChars[10]; // array to hold multiple single arrays of characters
```

Since the arrayOfChars is being used like a buffer (new data always goes there first), you'll need to save a copy of the string into the arrayOfArrays. The POSIX function `strdup` should help here.

Notice `&` and `*` are opposites, so `&*` and `*&` do absolutely nothing.

You could also, make the arrayOfArrays literally that.

```
char arrayOfChars[50]; // a single array of characters
char arrayOfArraysOfChars[10][50]; // array to hold multiple single arrays of characters
```

With this setup, you should use `strcpy` to copy the data into arrayOfArrays.

---

Having read your edit, I think you need to start *real* simple. And FWIW the variable names are the wrong kind of Hungarian.

For what I think you're trying to do, I'd start with just a single char array. This will be the main *buffer*, to hold strings that are being input and examined.

```
enum { BUFSZ = 50 };
char buf[BUFSZ + 1];
```

Then you can use it with `fgets` or whatever.

```
fgets(buf, BUFSZ, infile);
```

To save these up in an array, I'd use `strdup` for its automatic trimming. If the strings are going to be mostly 2 characters long, I don't want 48 extra bytes being used for each one. So, an array of char pointers (strings).

```
enum { STRVSZ = 40 };
char *strv[STRVSZ + 1];
int i;
i = 0;
strv[i] = strdup(buf);
strv[i+1] = NULL; // This makes it an "argv-style" NULL-terminated array of strings
++i; // i is now the index of the next element, and a count of elements already added
```

Each element of `strv` is a char pointer. But to preserve our sanity, we're trying to *abstract away* some of that distracting detail for a moment, and treat *strings* as a separate data type.

Now to create lists of these, we do the same thing again. But there's no `strdup`-type function to make a duplicate of an array of pointers, so we have to separate the allocation and copying.

```
enum { STRVVSZ = 20 };
char **strvv[STRVVSZ + 1];
int j;
j = 0;
strvv[j] = calloc(i+1, sizeof *strvv[j]); // assuming i is the count of elements 
memcpy(strvv[j], strv, i * sizeof *strvv[j]);
++j; // j is now the index of the next string-pointer array in the array-of-same,
     // and a count of elements already added.
```

Now, my names are just as silly as yours, but they're *shorter!*

Comment: This is very close to nabbing the issue, but did not quite get it.  I do actually need an array that holds multiple single arrays of characters (I will refer to arrays of characters as strings), but I also need an array that holds multiple arrays of strings.  Give me a moment to update the OP with clearer language.

Comment: This is at least theoretically exactly what I needed :).  I'm not sure why the memcpy doesn't seem to be working, but I'll post details in a separate question.  As far as the scope of this question is concerned, this is an excellent answer.

Comment: I've edited to add `++i;` and `++j;` and comments on the importance of those lines.

Answer (score 7):

you should learn what an array means.
an array is basically a set of *integer* or *character* or *anything*.
when you are storing a character value in an array, define it as,

```
char array[] = {"somestringhere"};
```

now you want to store such arrays in an another array. it is simple:

```
char* array1[];
```

the array1 will store values, which are of `char*` type i.e. the address of character arrays.
now you want to store these in other array,

```
char** array2[];
```

this is, array of [address of arrays]
now, all you have to do is;

```
array1[0] = array; //same as: array1[0] = *array[0];
array2[0] = *array1[0];
```

Now you've everything you need.
Hope you are clear, to the core. :)

Comment: This was also helpful in clearing up what I'm trying to do, thanks.  Now just need to figure out a way to make the pointer change.

Answer (score 5):

This example was done with turbo c+ 1.01 dos and works in the 3.0 dos version also.

```
char * text[] = {
  "message1",
  "message2",
  "message3"
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that your examples show arrays of pointers. If you want arrays of arrays (multidimensional arrays) specify all the sizes in the array definition.

```
char sentences[500][42]; /* sentences is an array of 500 elements.
                         ** each element is itself an array
                         ** capable of holding strings up to length 41 */
```

Comment: You might like to read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) which explains much better than I ever could why **arrays are not pointers** and **pointers are not arrays**.

Answer (score 1):

if storing text in a .c or .h file having more than one line of text, equivalent
to the idea of an array of char arrays.  can do this:

```
char * text[] = {
  "message1",
  "message2",
  "message3"
};
```

can also use char *text[], char near *text[], char far *text[], char huge *text[]. has to have an asterisk or star character for a pointer.

a for loop can be used to display text:

```
char i; // int type can also be used
for (i = 0, i < 3; i++)
  printf("%s\n", text[i]);
```

other loops:

```
char i = 0;  // may not be zero when declared as "char i;" only
while (i < 3) {
  printf("%s\n", text[i]);
  i++;
 }
```

or

```
char i = 0;  // may not be zero when declared as "char i;" only
do {
 printf("%s\n", text[i]);
 i++;
} while (i < 3);
```